# ApiController as WPF ViewModelBase

Tags: wpf, asp.net-web-api

Can I use `ApiController` as `ViewModelBase` in the `WPF` app?

If yes , How can I handle bindings validation etc ... ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could but that makes no sense. ApiController is Web technology, WPF is desktop technology.

Why Not ApiController:

- It is in System.Web.Http - why do you need this dependency for desktop
  application
- It inherits IHttpController - this is not a desktop technology - you are dragging in lot of concepts that have nothing to do with how desktop applications process information
- Does not have any idea about IPropertyNotifyChange which
  what ViewModelBase from MVVM Light toolkit has to enable property
  notification changes

Comment: thanx but why not? could u explan more?